# How do I reference the only element in a singleton set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

You can turn any element $n$ into a singleton set by adding braces, $\{n\}$. Is there an inverse to this operation, such that if I know the set is a singleton set I can easily reference its element?

For example, say I have the set $A = \{5,6,7,8\}$, and then some process that iteratively eliminates all but one element of $A$, and then I want to see what 10 plus the resulting element is, how could I write that?

The only way I can think of is by referencing the first element by its index, e.g., $10 + A_1$. Is there another way to do it though? In my case the elements of $A$ are already indices, so I would have to index an index, like $10 + x_{A_1}$. Which is not the worst thing in the world, I was just wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: I have never seen a notation for that. I know that the software Maple uses the command "op" for that purpose. Not that it is the best choice of notation, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply define a function

$\text{the} : \wp(X) \to X : \{x\} \mapsto x$

that maps every singleton set to its only element (*the* element $x$, which is the only member of $\{x\}$).

Then e.g. $\text{the}(\{5\})+10 = 5+10 = 15$.

I have not seen this notation used anywhere in practice, though.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. Thanks, I will work something out based on this I think.

Comment: It *is* used "in practice" in the Isabelle/HOL proof-assistant, although that's hardly a "widespread use" example. In that system, the name is `THE` rather than `the`, however.

Comment: Isn't there a missing Empty-Set in the({5})? Since the source domain is the power set and {5} is not a power set.

Comment: @Shaki No. The power set operation is on the domain, not on the input. $\mathrm{the}$ is a function whose domain is a set of sets of objects (all singleton sets) and whose codomain is a set of objects (all objects extracted from those sets), so an input coming from that domain is a set of objects.

Comment: @lemontree Thank. I still have a final question though. 
Shouldn't  the definition then be the:℘({X})→X ? [I am adding the set brackets to X]
Otherwise, how would you solve the({5,6}) since {5,6} is in the powerset of {5,6}. Also because the powerset is defined on a set and not an element.

Comment: @Shaki No. That would mean that the possible inputs are the empty set and a set containing the set. But you need just the set. The domain and codomain are simply the sets of the inputs and outputs. So for a function where the input is a set of objects and the output is an object, the domain is a set of sets of objects and the codomain is a set of objects.

Comment: But you are correct that $\mathrm{the}(\{5,6\})$ is not solvable, for non-singleton sets the function is undefined. So the way I wrote it it's a partial function, to be more precise one would have to specify the domain to be the subset with those sets which have exactly one element: $\{Y \in \wp(X): |Y| = 1\} \to X$

Answer (score 4):

A singleton set is a set with only one element. Thus, we can say "**the** element of" that set without error, because every element of $\{ a \}$ is equal to $a$.

We can use the [Description operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_description#Mathematical_logic) :

> "Following the example of *Principia Mathematica*, it is customary to use a definite description operator symbolized using the "turned" (rotated) Greek lower case iota character "$℩$".
>
> The notation $℩ x(\phi x)$ means "the unique $x$ such that $\phi x$".

Thus :

> > $a= ℩ x( x \in \{ a \})$.

Comment: Isn't there a clean way to do the "turned" iota in LateX ?

Comment: @OlivierRoche - I've tried with "\riota" and "\turnediota", but without success.

Comment: @Oliver Roche In ordinary LaTeX (though not the slimmed MathJax as on MathSE), you could simply `\rotatebox{180}{$\iota$}` with `\usepackage{graphicx}`.